# PHP dateperiod function does not return anything

Tags: php, date

I need to find the dates between a set of dates, so am trying to use DatePeriod for it. I began by trying this sample code:

```
$start = new DateTime('2012-07-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P7D');
$end = new DateTime('2012-07-31');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end,DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
var_dump($period);
```

The DateTime and DateInterval objects var_dump correct data. But the DatePeriod object does not give me any range! `object(DatePeriod)#5 (0) {}`

This works fine in my laptop, I get the date range returned. The issue is when I run this in my server. The PHP version in the server is 5.3.3. PHP site states that DatePeriod only needs PHP >-5.3.0.

Does anyone have any suggestions on whats going on here? Much appreciated!

Comment: [Might be a version thing](https://3v4l.org/0IjXK)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to PHP version 5.4.17, the internals of the DatePeriod object were "hidden", and wouldn't reveal anything when var_dumped.

However, it was still iterable, so a `foreach` loop over the DatePeriod object would still return a series of dates for that period

Comment: Unfortunately it does not iterate for me either. I put it in another server with PHP 5.6 and it works like a charm. Unfortunately I cannot use that server for running this script...

Comment: Unfortunately [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0CkWF) only covers PHP 5.4 upwards now.